# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) when embedding YouTube video

Tags: reactjs, youtube, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to embed a video from YouTube or Google Drive but whenever I put the embed link into the iframe, I get:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response URL preview with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a server.

Comment: That might the problem. I think that it worked locally but it doesn't work on Heroku.